# WordPress save_post_{custom_post_type} hook after all post meta is saved

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-hook

Literally the save_post wp hook get triggered before the post meta data is saved.
That's why I am facing an issue.
Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the hook function, you can simply get the updated meta value like below. `$_REQUEST[$meta_key]`

You can update the post meta right away if you want.